# ¿Cómo hacer que la banda Column Footer se oculte dinámicamente en Jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tengo un reporte hecho en ***iReport***. Incluí un `textFieldExpression` en la banda `columnFooter` del reporte, el cual va a mostrarse cuando se cumpla la condición de no ser `null`. He seleccionado `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` pero el espacio de la banda se sigue mostrando y quiero que ese espacio también se quite ya que me está mandando el resto de campos a otra hoja.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<columnFooter>
    <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{descripcionComentario}!=null]]>
        </printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement
                x="42"
                y="0"
                width="100"
                height="12"
                uuid="5a9cbe9d-486a-4dd4-a865-d421cd7366a6"
            />
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression>
                <![CDATA[$F{descripcionComentario}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
```

Comment: Queres que se oculte dinámicamente? con un campo de la base datos o con que valor?

Comment: Sí, exactamente con un campo de la base de datos. Que cuando este sea null se oculte tanto el campo como la banda.